# ngIf doesn't update with variable

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-material, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I have a very simple ng-if construction using two MD buttons and one AngularJS scope variable `isPlaying`. However, the ng-if doesn't seem to work along with the variable. I can see the variable changing as I click the buttons, using console tools, however no changes to the DOM. Strangely enough the ng-if does seem to trigger when I hover other Angular components, such as buttons in the main nav.

HTML/MD/PHP:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-if="!isPlaying" ng-click="play()" aria-label="Play">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon/ic_play_arrow_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-if="isPlaying" ng-click="pause()" aria-label="Pause">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon/ic_pause_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.play = function () {
    player.playVideo();
    $scope.isPlaying = true;
}

$scope.pause = function () {
    player.pauseVideo();
    $scope.isPlaying = false;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/bv7dyhvc/

Comment: Ok. Any tips on how to proceed next? Because the fiddle is simply a confirmation of that it should work, not a reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Then try to create a jsfiddle/plunker that reproduces your problem. I don't see how anyone can help you if we can't see the problem.

Comment: Try injecting $timeout and in your functions do something like this `$timeout(function () {$scope.isPlaying = true;});

Comment: @yarons I have no idea how jsfiddle works, but I gave it a go: https://jsfiddle.net/sjorshijgenaar/aapsho8h/2/ it's not working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by a function wrapped inside a timeout block. I replaced the `setTimeout` with `$timeout` and everything started working fine:

```
$scope.isPlaying = false;
$scope.videoTime = 0;
function onPlayerStateChange() {
    console.log(player);
    if (player.getPlayerState() === 1)
        $scope.isPlaying = true;
    else
        $scope.isPlaying = false;
    $timeout(onPlayerStateChange, 500);
}
```